# Is there a resource that lists what case(s) verbs govern?

Tags: глаголы

In Russian, there are verbs that govern a certain case, but also verbs that can be used with more than one case (typically verbs that take either the accusative or the genitive-partitive).

Would there be a resource that lists verbs with the cases they govern?

Comment: This looks like something that could be of use but I can't see inside it: https://www.amazon.co.uk/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-ebook/dp/B0184KH8LG

Comment: As you are dissatisfied with the given answers, people have no idea what you are asking about. Try paraphrasing your question.

Answer (score 2):

This link might be what you are looking for.  http://masterrussian.net/f15/list-verbs-require-dative-genitive-instrumental-case-20791/

Answer (score -2):

In Russian, the following nominals are declined (case-changing): nouns, adjectives, numerals, participles, and pronouns. Declension is expressed by endings.